# Remote Validation with elements containing special characters

Tags: jquery, validation, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm trying to use the Remote Validation feature built into ASP.net MVC 3, which I've used a few other times successfully.  However, due to a form element on the page having a name that includes "[" and "]" (a collection off of the main model), I can't seem to use Remote Validation.

The Html that is being rendered on my page is:

```
<input id="Leads_0__OpenDate" class="datepicker medium hasDatepicker valid" type="text"  name="Leads[0].OpenDate" data-val-required="Open Date is required." data-val="true">
```

Usually, I would just add this to my ViewModel for the OpenDate field:

```
[Remote("ValidateOpenDate", "Opportunity", ErrorMessage = "The open date can not be in the future.")]
```

However, since the field is part of a collection of Leads, it gets posted back to the ValidateOpenDate action as "Leads[0].OpenDate", which is not a valid name to put in the parameters, since C# doesn't allow "[" or "]" in the variable name.

Is there anything I can do to get remote validation working, instead of just writing some custom javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public ActionResult ValidateOpenDate()
{
    var openDate = Request["Leads[0].OpenDate"];
    ...
}
```

or (untested, not sure if it will work because of the brackets):

```
public ActionResult ValidateOpenDate([Bind(Prefix = "Leads[0]")] string openDate)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch! Why didn't I think of just using the Request?  The Bind Prefix unfortunately did not work, but Request is fine!

Answer (score 1):

Actually the second case needs to look like

```
    public ActionResult ValidateOpenDate([Bind(Prefix = "Leads[0].OpenDate")] string openDate)
    {
        ...
    }
```

Probably heard that elsewhere but just documenting it here as well.