# How to use MVC3 remote validation on collection elements in a model?

Tags: jquery, validation, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm using the MVC3 remote validation feature rather happily until I came across a collection in the page that needs to be edited.  On our view we are using a data grid like construct (collection bound to the appropriate edit view) for the editing of all the elements at the 'same' time. I am familiar with the Bind(Prefix= but when it comes to using with collections it seems to be somewhat lacking due to the fact that there does not seem to be a wildcard that can be applied to this decoration.

```
    public JsonResult AValidator([Bind(Prefix="CollectionName[*].ValuetoValidate") string ValuetoValidate) { ... }
```

You either have to put in a csv list of all the anticipated elements in the collection or do a more complex version of whats suggested here [Remote Validation with elements containing special characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6372374/remote-validation-with-elements-containing-special-characters/6372456#6372456) in using Request which brings string parsing into the picture (which is something I trying to avoid by using MVC3 in the 1st place).

Is there a better way?!?!?

Comment: A thought would be to perhaps approach this from the JavaScript side of things.

Comment: 1 of these days I'll slap together a hashtable corrector function for this and see what happens.